# External URL in Phonegap

Tags: android, url, cordova, hyperlink, phonegap-plugins

I want to open a link say www.google.com in Phonegap Android... I've tried lot of things but I'm not able to open any link.

`<access origin="http://google.com" />` is already added to config.xml.

`navigator.app.loadUrl('http://google.com');` is giving an error.

```
$('#pageID').load('http://google.com',function(){
$('#pageID').trigger('create');
});
```

is loading the page but the images are not displayed, which is required in my case.

Can anyone explain how to actually open a link in Phonegap.

Comment: Do you want to load the page as a trusted page inside your app or do you want it to load in a web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems its not possible ..... but I found that we can do it other way round.

We know this works :-

```
 <a data-role="none" id="someID" href="#" target="_blank">
```

So we can write jQuery as :-

```
$('#idAnchorTag').attr('href','some URL');
```

So the complete code is :- (Assuming that click was made on an image)

```
   <a data-role="none" id="idAnchorTag" href="#" target="_blank">
    <img id="idIMG" src="some IMAGE">
   </a>
```

And the JS :-

```
$(function() {
   $("#idIMG").click(function(){

      $('#idAnchorTag').attr('href','some URL');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#pageID').onClick(function(){
    document.location.href="http://google.com";
})
```